# How can I grab with ffmpeg only if there is a change in the input?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to grab my x11 desktop with ffmpeg into a video file.

However, it happens often that the desktop actually doesn't change. I want to miss this from the recorded video. Thus, the recorded video should contain only a continuously moving desktop.

For example, if I record a 10 minute long video, but I did anything in only 1 minute of it, then I want to see an 1 minute long recording.

Currently I use the command

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :0 -filter_complex "select='gt(scene,0.01)'" out.mp4
```

for that. If I understand the docs well, it should skip the consecuting same frames.

However, not this is happening. The recorded video is still 10 minute long, only there are some "jumps" in it.

Is there some tricky flag (maybe some "filter_complex" settings), what could simply remove the consecutive same screens from the grab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select filter won't adjust the timestamps of the retained frames, so the trick is to adjust them so that the gaps are removed.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :0 -filter_complex "select='gt(scene,0.01)',setpts='if(eq(N\,0),0,PREV_OUTPTS+if(lte(T-PREV_INT\,3.0)\,(T-PREV_INT)/TB\,2/TB))'" out.mp4
```

If there's a gap of more than 3 seconds between timestamps of adjacent retained frames, their gap is reduced to 2 seconds.

You may need to experiment with the scene change value to avoid capturing portions where only the clock or network icon changes..etc

Comment: Thanks the answer! However, it says, "`[Parsed_setpts_1 @ 0x5562bdf9b4c0] [Eval @ 0x7ffd049e2d10] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'PREV_T)/TB,2/TB))'`" :-( I am trying to find a solution, but if you would help... :-)

Comment: typos, corrected.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I needed. :-)